# Can you show me a path for $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2 - y)\cdot y}{x^4} \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I've been trying differents paths for this limit. They all resulted in the limit being $0$, so I've tried an epsilon-delta definition but reached a contradiction.. my guess is that the limit doesn't exist and I just can't come up with a curve that will prove it.

> $$   \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2 - y)\cdot y}{x^4} & 0<y<x^2 \\
>       0 &  otherwise\\
> \end{array} 
> \right. $$

Can you show me a path? Going along the axis, straight lines and parabolas didn't work for me...

Comment: I believe you'll want to make it more clear that you want $0<y<x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a simplistic approach and assume the $x=x(t),\ y=y(t)$ and apply L'Hôpital's rule. Thus,

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2 - y) y}{x^4} = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}(x^2 - y) y}{\frac{d}{dt}x^4}=\frac{x^2\dot y+2xy\dot x-y\dot y}{4x^3\dot x}$$

The object is to choose $y=f(x)$ so as to cancel the $x$-terms in the numerator an denominator. The clear choice is $y=ax^2,\ \dot y=2ax\dot x$. Following through it can readily be shown that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2 - y) y}{x^4} = a-a^2$$

as was demonstrated intuitively earlier by @florence.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we approach $(0,0)$ along the path $(x,y)=(t,at^2)$ where $0<a<1$. Then the limit along this path is
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{at^4-a^2t^4}{t^4} = a-a^2$$
which is usually not equal to $0$.

Comment: I think you'll want $0<y<x^2$, as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take the limit along a path on the curve $y=ax^2$, for fixed $a$ with $0 < a < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(t,0)$ where $t$ tends to $0$, and $(t,-t^2)$, $t$ tends to $0$.